# Delete in cloud firestore gives "doc.delete is not a function"

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete one document and also delete a specific subcollection from it. I am using a web client. How can I retrieve all documents in a subcollection and delete them? Here is what I have right now:

```
let id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
        if (accountType == 'admin') {
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this event?")) {

        db.collection('campouts').doc(docIdDoc).collection('attending').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                doc.delete();
            });
        });

        db.collection('campouts').doc(id).delete().then(() => {
        });
```

When I click the button I get this error in the console:

> script.js:123 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: doc.delete is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `doc` in your code is `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, which is the in-memory snapshot of a document's data. To delete a document you need a `DocumentReference`, which you can get from the snapshot's `ref` property.

So:

```
db.collection('campouts').doc(docIdDoc).collection('attending').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        doc.ref.delete();
    });
});
```

For problems like this, I highly recommend keeping the reference documentation handy. You can follow the trail from [`Query.get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get) -> `QuerySnapshot` -> `QueryDocumentSnapshot` -> `DocumentSnapshot` -> `ref` -> `DocumentReference`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I made your code use async/await as promise chaining is to me, messy.

```
const mainFunction = async () => {
  const refs = await db
    .collection('campouts')
    .doc(docIdDoc)
    .collection('attending')
    .get()

  await Promise.all(
    refs.map(async (doc) => {
      await doc.ref.delete()
    }),
  )
}
mainFunction()
```